# non-calculus proof that $|x| + |y| \le \sqrt{2} |z|$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, complex-numbers

I would like to see a nice, non-calculus proof that $|x| + |y| \le \sqrt{2} |z|$, where $z$ is the complex number $x + iy$. The more elementary the better, avoiding even trig if possible. Thank you.

Comment: How about formulating it as $$\frac{|x|+|y|}{2} \leq \sqrt{\frac{|x|^2+|y|^2}{2}}$$ and recognizing it as Cauchy–Schwarz in different garb?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.  Your inequality follows from:

$$\begin{align}
(|a|-|b|)^2 \geq 0 &\Longrightarrow a^2 + b^2 \geq 2|a||b|
\\
&\Longrightarrow 2(a^2 + b^2) \geq (|a|+|b|)^2
\\
&\Longrightarrow \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \geq |a| + |b|
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

(This is pretty similar to DJC's answer)

Squares of real numbers are non-negative:

$$\begin{align}
( |x| + |y| )^2 
& \leq ( |x|+|y| )^2 + (|x|-|y|)^2 \\
& = (|x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2|xy|) + (|x|^2 + |y|^2 - 2|xy|) \\
&= 2|x|^2 + 2|y|^2 \\
&= 2|z|^2
\end{align}$$

Taking square roots:

$$|x|+|y| \leq \sqrt{2}|z|$$

Answer (score 1):

By dividing by $|z|$, it suffices to prove:  For any unit modulus complex number, $x + iy$, we have $ |x| + |y| \leq \sqrt{2} $.  A unit modulus complex number is represented by a point $(x, y)$ on the unit circle.  The maximum of the sum of $|x|$ and $|y|$ must occur when $|x|=|y|$ (why?), at which point Pythagoras tells us that $|x|=|y|= \sqrt{2}/2$, and hence $|x|+|y| = \sqrt{2}$.